# Must declare the scalar variable - Setting variable equal to a SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to set `@inputData` as the rows of a select statement, then pass it into my `DoSomething` stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @inputData [dbo].[TestTableType];

SET @inputData = ( 
    SELECT
        1 AS Client_Id,
        20170202 AS a,
        18595 AS b,
        49.82 AS c,
        88 AS d,
        31 AS e,
        0.67 AS f,
        0 AS g,
        44 AS h,
        1827 AS i,
        5 AS j,
        87 AS k
);

EXEC DoSomething @inputData;
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@inputData".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note sure, maybe try `insert into @inputData select ...`

Comment: Thanks @user1429080 Works perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't `SET` table variables. You `INSERT` into them:

```
INSERT INTO @inputData /* Should have column list here also */
SELECT
        1 AS Client_Id,
        20170202 AS a,
        18595 AS b,
        49.82 AS c,
        88 AS d,
        31 AS e,
        0.67 AS f,
        0 AS g,
        44 AS h,
        1827 AS i,
        5 AS j,
        87 AS k
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with INSERT INTO. Think of a table type as literally a temp table (it basically is).

```
DECLARE @inputData AS TestTableType

INSERT INTO @inputData 
SELECT
    1 AS Client_Id,
    20170202 AS a,
    18595 AS b,
    49.82 AS c,
    88 AS d,
    31 AS e,
    0.67 AS f,
    0 AS g,
    44 AS h,
    1827 AS i,
    5 AS j,
    87 AS k
);
```

Comment: I seem to get the same issue. In all fairness, my User-Defined Table Type is in fact called dbo.TestTableType